# While returning no results

Tags: php

I've got the following query in an existing script - but it's not always returning a value even though it should based off what's in the database.  There are plenty of things in the database it SHOULD be grabbing - they are there.

Don't see anything wrong with it - but I barely do this anymore :) See anything?

```
$query = "SELECT id FROM xtags WHERE tag_id = '$tagid' ORDER BY RAND() Limit 2";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

            $query = "SELECT * FROM xtable WHERE id = '$row[id]'";
            $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
            $row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            echo $row2[title];

}
```

Comment: inefficient, could be done with 1 query. learn JOIN

Comment: You could do the same with only one sql query

Comment: No doubt - just doing some debugging here.

Comment: fixing the queries so you don't have to use a loop will solve the issue in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved - did a join statement.

Answer (score 4):

$result is being used inside the loop and outside, try making a new variable inside and not reusing the outside one.

Answer (score 2):

You're reusing the `$result` variable inside the loop which overwrites the value for use in the `while` condition.  Use a different name for `$query` and `$result` inside the loop.

Comment: That's not it Nick.  Still returning the occasional "no result" sets.

Comment: ..and you're certain that your SQL statements are correct?  There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your code which leaves your SQL queries as the culprit for further issues you may be experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if is ok, but you are using $result twice, one before the "while" and another inside the "while".

I would  personally split the string and the variable $row.

Why not use var_dump() to see $row and the other variables ???

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you are trying to do actually, but try this:

```
$query = "SELECT id FROM xtags WHERE tag_id = '".$tagid."' ORDER BY RAND() Limit 2";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

            $query2 = "SELECT * FROM xtable WHERE id = '".intval($row[id])."'";
            $result2 = mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());
            $row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2);
            echo $row2[title];

}
```